# From which server did i get query response in dnsmasq

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I'm running a test machine with dnsmasq in it. Dnsmasq uses dns servers 8.8.8.8 and 4.2.2.1 for testing purposes. I'm not using strict order in config. Is it possible to see which of these configured servers reply first in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use tcpdump, if available:

```
sudo tcpdump -i yourinterface -n host 8.8.8.8 or host 4.2.2.1
```

This would produce multiple lines showing you the communication between the two dns servers and your host.

If you want to limit the number of lines in the output before tcpdump quits, you can add the `-c` parameter. See `man tcpdump` for details.